# a particular use of Route command in Windows (Local Route)

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, routing

i have seen a co-worker set a command like

> route add 192.168.4.20  10.167.0.198

in his computer to access services provided by a server on my network without changing his IP address or passing trough a router (they just plug his network on my switch and wrote this command on his machine and started to work), now i am trying to do the same for a test but it doesn't work.

here my setup:

- Server X2 (3rd part, possibly a linux machine, I access it through his custom software) on 10.167.0.198\24
- PC (win 7 pro) to 192.167.0.28\24

I wrote this in the prompt

> route add  192.167.0.29  10.167.0.198

and my routing table have this line

```
Network Address - Mask            - Gateway      - Interface    - Metric
192.167.0.29    - 255.255.255.255 - 10.167.0.198 - 192.168.0.28 - 11
```

i've tried deleting the previous line and swapping addresses but none of this config seem to work

what am i missing (apart a proper networking expertise)?

could windows 7 be stopping this because he thinks he is in a public network?

are there other setting to allow this?

UPDATE

the thing i'm tryng to do is similar to this https://serverfault.com/questions/115654/windows-static-routes-w-o-specifying-gateway-next-hop

on the first part he setup a local Route,but I'm having trouble doing this 
i tried to add

> route add  192.167.0.28  10.167.0.198

still no succes

Comment: See route command details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx

Comment: You would have to actually look at the IP configuration to see whenever it matches. As you can see you are setting a Gateway which usually is a router.

Comment: i am tryng that in a Test environment in my network, i can set my pc however i want, but i'm shure  192.167.0.28 and  10.167.0.198 exists, are you suggesting to increase my netmask range on the pc? or should i match the routing mask to the actual mask of the server?

Comment: I'm suggesting that your network configuration is important and you're lacking details. For example your route output shows that you're able to reach `192.167.0.29` through a router `10.167.0.198` on interface `192.168.0.28`. Which means you won't be able to reach the router without further configuration as it is in a different network segment. If you look at the [help for route](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx) you will find a good description of gateway. Without changing other parameters just adding a route will be insufficient to connect different networks.

Comment: _"Gateway   : Specifies the forwarding or next hop IP address over which the set of addresses defined by the network destination and subnet mask are reachable. **For locally attached subnet routes, the gateway address is the IP address assigned to the interface that is attached to the subnet.**  ....."_ and  10.167.0.198 is attached to the same switch, i know that 192.167.0.29 doesen't exist, and i woudn't have tought of doing this, but this guy did it wthout changing anything on my server, it appear like a NAT (10.167.0.198 becoming 192.167.0.29) done just with route command in a .bat